# why strcat producing this error?

Tags: c, arrays, strcat, lzw

`[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast` THIS ERROR IS COMING WHEN I AM USING STRCAT WHAT SHOULD I DO , below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char a[20], b[256], p = NULL, f;
    int i, j, n, k, c[20], t, x, l;
    printf("enter the no of possible characters");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("enter the possible characters in the dictionary");
    printf("hi");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        c[i] = (i);
        a[i] = getchar();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf("%d  %s\n ", c[i], a[i]);
    }
    l = k;

    printf("enter the string\n");
    scanf("%s", &b);
    n = strlen(b);
    printf("%d", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        strcat(p, b[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Don;t shout, please.

Comment: Because `strcat` wants a NUL terminated `string`, not a `char`

Comment: Because `b[i]` is not the required pointer, but an array element of the wrong type.

Comment: @Rachit  Tell us by secret what are you trying to achieve?:)

Answer (score 3):

This is because `strcat` takes null-terminated strings, not individual characters. You can work around this problem by null-terminating `b` at position `n`, and calling `strcat` once:

```
b[n] = '\0';
strcat(p, b);
```

This will append the initial `n` characters of `b` to `p`, all in one go. Of course, given that `p` does not have any characters in it, this is completely pointless: you might as well use `strcpy`. Of course, you need to declare `p` to be a character buffer large enough to hold all of `b`:

```
char a[20],b[256],p[256]={0},f;
//                 ^^^^^^^^^
b[n] = '\0';
strcpy(p, b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable definition is wrong.

```
  char a[20],b[256],p=NULL,f;
```

**does not** define `p` as a pointer. It is a `char` variable with is not the expected type for the first argument of `strcat()`.

You need to define `p` as a pointer to a string which has enough memory to hold the concatenated result.

That said,

```
 strcat(p,b[i]);
```

is completely wrong, because `b[i]` is not a pointer to a *string*, either.

Comment: @WeatherVane I never intended to say that just making `p` a pointer would solve the issue, however, elaborated to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ah but OP might have thought it enough to change the type.